# Wixcode "static" html iframe

Tags: html, velo

Apologies if this is not the correct place to post this. I'm completely new to HTML and such, but I wanted to put a button on my website which would remember how many times it been pressed and each time someone presses it it give you a number, say for example the next prime number. With enough googleing I managed to put together some (what I expect is really bad code) which I thought could do this. This is what I have (sorry if its not formatted correctly, I had trouble with copy pasting).

```
<head>
    <title>Space Clicker</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function isPrime(_n)
   {
    var _isPrime=true;
    var _sqrt=Math.sqrt(_n);
     for(var _i=2;_i<=_sqrt;_i++)
     if((_n%_i)==0) _isPrime=false;
      return _isPrime;
    }   
    function nextPrime(_s,_n)
    {
  while(_n>0)if(isPrime(_s++))_n--;
    return --_s;
    }

var clicks = 0;
function hello() {
    clicks += 1;
    v = nextPrime(2,clicks);
    document.getElementById("clicks1").innerHTML = clicks ;
     document.getElementById("v").innerHTML = v ;
};
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="hello()">Get your prime</button>
<p>How many primes have been claimed: <a id="clicks1">0</a></p>
   <p>Your prime: <a id="v">0</a></p>


</body>
```

The problem is that when I put this code in a iframe on my wixsite it seems to reload the code each time you look at the site, so it starts the counter again. What I would like it say the button has been pressed 5 times, it will stay at 5 until the next visitor comes along and presses it. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: If you want some data to persist, you would probably need to look at localStorage or a server side language.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need an iframe for that, You can use wixCode to do that. WixCode let's you have a DB collection. and all you need to do is update the collection values on every click.

Let's say you add an Events collection can have the fields: 
id, eventName, clicksCount

add to it a single row with eventName = 'someButtonClickEvent' and clicksCount = 0
Then add the following code to your page:

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';

$w.onReady(function () {});

export function button1_click(event) {
    wixData.get("Events", "the_event_id")
      .then( (results) => {
        let item = results;
        let toSave = {
           "_id": "the_event_id",
           "clicksCount":   item.clicksCount++
        };

        wixData.update("Events", toSave)
    })
}
```

now you need to add button1_click as the onClick handler of your button (in the wixCode properties panel).